# Lightning component loses event bindings

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, jquery, aura

I've got a custom Lightning component that works well. However, as soon as I detach it from the DOM, and put it somewhere else (with jQuery e.g. to ease UI development), it loses most of its event handlers (e.g. button click).

Example:

```
<aura:component>....
   <div id="wrapper1">
     <c:myComponent />
   </div>
   <div id="wrapper2">
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Now, when I now run some jQuery code in afterScriptsLoaded, such as this:

```
jQuery('#wrapper1').appendTo('#wrapper2');
```

The event handlers are lost. I don't know why this happens. Even when I use jQuery's clone method with all the "copy event handler" arguments it will lose event handlers.

What's happening behind the scenes? Is there any documentation on how aura works in this regard? How can I attach the component somewhere else in the DOM and keep it working?

Edit: Upon further investigation, my individual problem seems to be related with css display styles. It could be that if you switch an element to display: none and then make it visible again, that it loses it's handlers.

Edit2: It really seems to be a css problem. It works when I use visibility: collapse instead of display: none;

Comment: that is strange! why not use the standard slds-hide/slds-show css classes?

Comment: @Roos Basset I use jquery components that work on their own classes.